# Run shell command in gradle but NOT inside a task

Tags: shell, gradle, build.gradle

What I currently have is:

```
task myTask (type : Exec) {
   executable "something.sh"
   ... (a lot of other things)
   args "-t"
   args ext.target
}

task doIt {
   myTask.ext.target = "/tmp/foo"
   myTask.execute();

   myTask.ext.target = "/tmp/gee"
   myTask.execute();
}
```

With this I thought I could run "myTask" with different parameters when I start "doIt". But only the first time the script is executed because gradle takes care that a task only runs once.
How can I rewrite the "myTask" so that I can call it more than once? It is not necessary to have it as a separate task.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```java
def doMyThing(String target) {
    exec {
        executable "something.sh"
        args "-t", target
    }
}

task doIt {
    doLast {
        doMyThing("/tmp/foo")
        doMyThing("/tmp/gee")
    }
}
```

The `exec` here is not a task, it's the [`Project.exec()`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec(groovy.lang.Closure)) method.

Comment: How do I provide multiple args in an array or list?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - Use `args myList` instead.